# Create orc table its not working

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have .tbl files stored in hdfs. And Im trying to create tables in hive with that .tbl files, but in orc format.

I started to create a table in text file:

```
create external table partsupp (PS_PARTKEY BIGINT,
 PS_SUPPKEY BIGINT,
 PS_AVAILQTY INT,
 PS_SUPPLYCOST DOUBLE,
 PS_COMMENT STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Then create in orc format:

```
 create table if not exists partsupporc (PS_PARTKEY BIGINT,
     PS_SUPPKEY BIGINT,
     PS_AVAILQTY INT,
     PS_SUPPLYCOST DOUBLE,
     PS_COMMENT STRING)
    STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Then load in the text table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tables/partsupp/partsupp.tbl' INTO TABLE partsupp;
```

Then copy the files into partsupporc table:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE partsupporc SELECT * FROM partsupp;
```

But its not working, Im getting this error:

`It appears Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there´s no reduce operator` and than stops.

Do you understand why its not working??

Comment: have you checked your table files on hdfs? the message you put is not an error, since the `INSERT ... SELECT FROM` is a map-only job, the message says thereis no reducers needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its not working, even the map job ist not executed, starts in 0% and then stops. And the table files exist in the hdfs. I didnt have any error creating and loading, just inserting with that select..

Comment: have you seen the yarn  logs? You may find something interresting there

Comment: It seems that is something about: ConnectTimeoutException: Call From nodeUbuntu/10.2.0.20 to 0.0.0.0:8031 failed on socket timeout exception org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeOutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect.

Comment: Seems that you have not started hadoop processes (yarn , hdfs) or you have not well configured them

Comment: But with jps command yarn appears started, and to create tables in hive works. And I also can execute "select * from partsupp" in hive and I get the select results.